# Reading .tiff data using Python

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, remote-sensing, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

[image][image: tiff]

I got none type while trying to open those tiff data. What issue could it possibly be?

I tried this:

```
import glob

images_tiff = []
for im in glob.glob(os.path.join(data_path, "*.tiff")):
    im = gdal.Open(os.path.join(data_path, im))
    images_tiff.append(im)
print( images_tiff)
```

```
[<osgeo.gdal.Dataset; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'GDALDatasetShadow *' at 0x000002DA79D68AB0> >, <osgeo.gdal.Dataset; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'GDALDatasetShadow *' at 0x000002DA79D68CF0> >, <osgeo.gdal.Dataset; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'GDALDatasetShadow *' at 0x000002DA79D68A20> >, <osgeo.gdal.Dataset; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'GDALDatasetShadow *' at 0x000002DA79D68B70> >, <osgeo.gdal.Dataset; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'GDALDatasetShadow *' at 0x000002DA79D68A80> >, <osgeo.gdal.Dataset; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'GDALDatasetShadow *' at 0x000002DA79D68D20> >, <osgeo.gdal.Dataset; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'GDALDatasetShadow *' at 0x000002DA79D68990> >, <osgeo.gdal.Dataset; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'GDALDatasetShadow *' at 0x000002DA79D68C00> >, <osgeo.gdal.Dataset; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'GDALDatasetShadow *' at 0x000002DA79D682D0> >, <osgeo.gdal.Dataset; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'GDALDatasetShadow *' at 0x000002DA79D68D50> >, <osgeo.gdal.Dataset; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'GDALDatasetShadow *' at 0x000002DA79D68C60> >]
```

Answer (score 2):

You path to the raster file is wrong. Probably you would like to open tiff files only, not all the files in the datapath folder.

Try this:

```
import glob
...
images = []
for img in glob.glob(os.path.join(datapath, "*.tif"):
    im = gdal.Open(os.path.join(datapath, img))
    images.append(img)
```

If you want to collect only the name of tif files, it is not necessary to open it with gdal (so you can remove the row with gdal.Open).
If you are not sure, that all tifs are valid you sould use try/except to filter invalid tif files e.g.:

```
import glob
...
images = []
for img in glob.glob(os.path.join(datapath, "*.tif"):
    try:
        im = gdal.Open(os.path.join(datapath, img))
    except:
        continue
    images.append(img)
```